Is there an evolutionary advantage to polycoria?
I tried to do some research on some scholarly articles on polycoria. "A REVIEW ON POLYCORIA" from N. Sankerneetha, et. al., states that the extra pupil dilates and reacts in response to light, although never expands on how a person with polycoria sees the world, so I couldn't extrapolate whether that would be beneficial for being selected.
Another article I found, From eye spots to eye shine from Ivan R. Schwab, wrote that the eye, as complex as it is, can definitely be evolved further. However, it was just an editorial that wrote about the complex eye structures of insecta and arthropoda. So I relay my question to the big web, is there any reason for organisms with similar visual inputs to ours to evolve polycoria not as a mutation?

Did you mean to ask this on our [medicalsciences.se] or our [biology.se] site? I ask as you've not included any worldbuilding context for your fictional world.

A good worldbuilding question would be, "I'm developing a species for my fictional world that evolved polycoria. I'm looking to rationalize behavior X, but cannot find literature about it on the web. Can the community help me rationalize X?" As written, this isn't a worldbuilding question, but a biology question - especially due to the [tag:hard-science] tag (which I'm willing to bet you didn't read about... ruthless, that tag). Very generally, evolution favors the simplest expression of the most beneficial adaptation - so you need to come up with a beneficial circumstance that needs it.

@JBH nature has created a creature that has something similar to polycoria (1 eye multiple pupils) in the body of a surface dwelling fish. Its not quite the same thing as polycoria, but it's pretty close.

I didn't do extensive research, but a website called "paireyewear" has an article describing the way someone with Polycoria sees the world. The main issue is that the pupil controls the amount of light let in, and having 2 pupils makes this process more complicated. In real world examples, the 2 pupils don't work in a synchronized way, so it ends up leading to glare effects (etc.) in one's vision, and they can struggle with double vision. I guess in theory, it's perhaps possible that having 2 pupils could lead to better night vision, but 1 pupil that can expand more probably does this better.

There are animals with weirdly-shaped pupils; seems to me a discrete pair of pupils is not so different.

It helps you fight nine tailed foxes.

It's straying from "hard science", so I'm not putting it as an answer, but with a little handwaving you could have them be able to see "interference patterns", which would open up whole new avenues of sensing.

"to evolve polycoria not as a mutation" what do you mean by that? Such a feature would definitely be a mutation. Are you asking whether it would be long term mutation that sticks around for many generations versus being so crippling that the initial mutated individual or close progeny would not procreate?

No
polycoria is a pathological condition, meaning something caused by a altered or caused by a disease, or is markedly abnormal. And having multiple pupils per iris for an entire species means that it is not caused/altered by a disease or markedly abnormal for a member of that species.
But
if you are instead talking about a creature with eyes that have multiple pupils per iris and that looks like polycoria as presented in humans/mammals and creatures that normally have only 1 pupil per eye, I don't have a hard science answer for this. And I don't have polycoria so can't draw on experience from that that to say what the benefits could be. All the eye doctor websites I looked at only list downsides from which I would have to draw a solid No.
But
There are several species that exists that has multiple pupils per eyeball but not however multiple pupils per iris. Which is close enough that I think it works to explain why a 'polycoria' eye might be evolutionarily advantageous with some caveats.

The creature is the Four-eyed fish. Which has an air pupil, and a water pupil on each eyeball, which are separated by a tissue band. They live at the water surface and sit with the top half of their eyeball sticking out of the water looking for insects to eat, while the bottom half of their eye helps them see what's in front so they don't run into things while chasing surface dwelling bugs/so they can see bigger/smaller fish. Light enters the air pupil/water pupil and is absorbed by a single lens. so despite their name, they only have 2 eyes, and not the 4 that their name/appearance would suggest. Their lenses are pretty complex and correct for the differences in refractive indices of air versus water which gives them good vision above/bellow the water, though they appear to have better vision with their air based-pupil then their water pupils.
So Yes there is an evolutionary advantage to having pupils that work well for 2 different environments. But I am not sure that the benefits outweigh the downsides of polycoria
Your species could develop polycoria like eyes, if they descend from a 2 eyed ancestor and end up living in the border between 2 different environments much like the 4-eyed fish, with a need to see well in both environments simultaneously (due to traveling in one while eating food from another for example).
The  caveat.
for a true polycoria look, the pupils are in the same iris, and close together. While each pupil can dilate/contract independently they aren't great at it (As each set of sphincters effect both pupils), and so people with polycoria have difficulty with bright lights, dim lights, and often suffer from blurry vision (and double vision) as they have difficulty focusing their pupils. Of course a species with polycoria would have evolved a fix to this problem, but I suspect that said fix might be the same fix that the 4 eyed fish has, separating that extra pupil into a it's own iris/cornea for each environment, and developing a firm tissue band between the pupils to anchor each pupil so that they can truly focus/dilate/contract independently from each other.
